# PrintWritter print POS tamil character in java

Tags: java, android

I have customer Billing application and I am using print Billing for POS printer. 
English characters are working perfectly but Chinese, Hindi, Arabic and Tamil fonts are not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.1.100",9100);              PrintWriter oStream = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                    //PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fil, false));

                    String BILL = new String("मराठी".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
                    PrintWriter out1 = null;

Answer (score 0):

For **Tamil** you can follow below steps:

1. Download the font you want to use for Tamil (`FontName.ttf`). And place it in `Assets` folder.
2. Import the library: https://github.com/mayooresan/Android-TamilUtil
3. Create a `TypeFace` and set to TextView (modify as required) as below:

`Typeface fontTamil = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/FontName.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(fontTamil);
textView.setText(TamilUtil.convertToTamil(TamilUtil.TSCII, "வணக்கம்"));`

**Sample Application:** https://github.com/mayooresan/Android-TamilUtil/tree/master/Example

Comment: thanks dude but i need POS printer support purpose. i have already display  Tamil font  in my application.